# Why do I have to declare these reference paramaters const or pass by value?

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

static const int NOT_FOUND = -1;

template <class sequence, class T>
int binarySearch(sequence& seq, int low, int high, T& item)
{
    //..
}

template <class sequence, class T>
int binarySearch(const sequence& seq, const T& item)
{
    if (seq.size() == 0)
        return NOT_FOUND;
    return binarySearch(seq, 0, seq.size() - 1, item);
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> t1 = {0, 3 ,45, 94};
    cout << binarySearch(t1, 0);
    //binarySearch(t1, 0, t1.size() - 1, 45);
    return 0;
}
```

Why does the compiler not accept:

```
template <class sequence, class T>
int binarySearch(sequence& seq, T& item)
```

?

Furthermore, why does the program as stated compile, but calling

```
binarySearch(t1, 0, t1.size() - 1, 45);
```

from main not compile?

The compiler error in any case is "No matching function for call to 'binarySearch'.

Comment: One issue that never use `t1.size()` with an int, `size()` returns an unsigned value, so you can first convert it to int, and then use it, like `int(t1.size())-1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you cannot bind a temporary object to a non-const reference.

```
binarySearch(t1, 0);
                 ^---- this is a temporary
```

If you stored `0` in a variable and used that, the [non-const version would work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/299c607e8831be62).

§ 8.5.4

> — Otherwise, if T is a reference type, a prvalue temporary of the type referenced by T is copy-list-initialized or direct-list-initialized, depending on the kind of initialization for the reference, and the reference is bound to that temporary. [ Note: As usual, the binding will fail and the program is ill-formed if the reference type is an lvalue reference to a non-const type. —end note

Comment: Ah yes rvalue can not bind to non-const. Is there relevant section of the standard for clarity?

Comment: @SteveM This is the only thing I could find in N3936